# how to use document.querySelector().innerHTML in react

Tags: reactjs

I'am trying to display the current time on display but don't know how to get it done.

```
function timer()
{
  let today = new Date(),
    hours = today.getHours(),
    minutes = today.getMinutes(),
    seconds = today.getSeconds();
    console.log(hours+'/'+minutes+'/'+seconds)


  setTimeout(timer,1000)
}


function App() {
  return (
    <div >

      <h1>Timer</h1>
      <h1 id='time'>Time : {timer()}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I expect output as Time : 12/5/12(i.e current time)

Comment: That's the example for use of state in docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 2):

You **don't** modify the `DOM` directly you use the return of your components to render and modify the `HTML`

First you will need to save the `time` in the component `state` using [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Second you will need to get the time when the component mounts using [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

Then render the `time` saved in the component `state` to the `DOM`

```
function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let today = new Date(),
      hours = today.getHours(),
      minutes = today.getMinutes(),
      seconds = today.getSeconds();

    const now = hours + "/" + minutes + "/" + seconds;
    console.log(now);

    setTime(now);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Timer</h1>
      {time && <h1 id="time">Time : {time}</h1>}
    </div>
  );
}
```